# Airflow DAG - Run on same day rather than 24 hours later

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have some DAGs that are used to query for records in a db that were created within a time window across 24 hour period so:

- 00.00am - 05:59am
- 06.00am - 11.59am
- 12.00pm - 17.59pm
- 18.00pm - 23.59pm

I'm struggling with Airflows scheduling system as right now, they always get executed 24 hours later, but i would rather the schedule runs just after each time window so i'm getting todays data faster and not having to wait until next day.

Can someone explain how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how Airflow's scheduling works. Airflow creates a DAG run at the end of an interval. So if you have a 6 hour interval from 00:00 to 06:00 (configured by `schedule_interval` on your DAG), Airflow creates a DAG run at 06:00. The start and end times of the interval can be used in templated values `data_interval_start` and `data_interval_end`. For example:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(dag_id="6hours", schedule_interval="0 0,6,12,18 * * *", start_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1)) as dag:
    BashOperator(
        task_id="print_templated_values",
        bash_command="echo 'Interval start is {{ data_interval_start }} and end is {{ data_interval_end }}'",
    )
```

For a DAG run created at 06:00, this would print: "Interval start is 2022-01-02T00:00:00+00:00 and end is 2022-01-02T06:00:00+00:00".

Comment: Thanks Bas, i was confusing myself a little as i was using logical_date as part of my sql query so it was using the previous day.

Now i've changed it to use execution date so i'm now getting the data for today.